# unable to run a cloned repo in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, version-control

I cloned a Beacon Library https://github.com/Codefy/onebeacon-android from github, it has some samples that i want to run, but as i cloned the repo my debug buttons become disabled.
[image: Debug Buttons]

The README file says that sample projects are ready to build, it would be really helpful if someone would explain how to run it.

[image: Project Structure]

i repeat that i want to run base service module on my deivce.
Thanks in advance.

**Solution**

It turned out that the right way to do was to :

(1) Open Android Studio, then File-> New -> import project -> select sample directory.

(2)Then fix the gradle issues.

(3) Select the specific module you want to run.

[image]

Comment: Check java files from `java` folder as your image shows. May be something is missing.

Comment: @EmptyBrain Actually the problem in the java files was due to gradle issues that i fixed later,all the time i was opening the project in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder and open it using the terminal. Clone the GitHub repo using the terminal (git clone https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxx.git). Then open it using the Android studio and you will be able to run it. I don't know how, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just Restart Your android Studio. It works for me.